# How soon I can re-enter in US, with b2 visa, if my previous stay was for two weeks?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, repeat-visits

How soon I can re-enter in USA with B2 Visa, if my previous stay was for two weeks?

Comment: I once did a re-entry circa 12 hours after being for ten days with No apparent issues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the next trip is for a similar duration (or fits within the period you were originally admitted for), there is no reason you would need to stay away for any particular period of time.

What's not allowed in tourist status is to try to *live* in the US, but two short visits do not add up to that no matter how close they are to each other.  You'd be allowed to stay continuously for several times two weeks anyway; breaking that up into smaller pieces will not make it look *more* like living in the US.